# Is there a free (LGPL< BSD, etc. ) RDF editor component for swing?

Tags: java, swing, rdf

I look for a JComponenet based RDF editor which I could embed in my application?

It does'n need to be fancy .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Swoop is a good editor that's released under an MIT style license. It's [available on Google code](http://code.google.com/p/swoop/source/browse/#svn/trunk). They also have an example test.java (http://code.google.com/p/swoop/source/browse/trunk/test.java) that seems to be a good start towards what you need.

Also, it was created by the team at the MIND lab in University of Maryland, including Bijan Parsia of Clark & Parsia.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's embeddable (or whether it even works), but take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/rdfeditor/.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

[Sourceforge jrdf](http://jrdf.sourceforge.net/)

or

[Java-source (for a list of tools)](http://java-source.net/open-source/rss-rdf-tools)

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a poke around in the source code of [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/) and steal anything that looks useful. It's under the Mozilla Public License.